# College algebra problem - Paying off debt and the interest rate associated

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a student who graduates with a $\$24,000$ debt.
They pay monthly compounded interest of 5% per year.
Ordinary annuities
First 5 years: $\$300$ per month
After 5 years: $\$200$ per month

Question #1: How long will it take to pay the debt?

Question #2:  How much will they pay in interest

Comment: Does the interest compound before the payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So his debt looks something like this:

$d_m = ...\frac{241}{240}(\frac{241}{240}(\frac{241}{240}(24000) - 300)-300)-300...$

You can see that each month you multiply by $\frac{241}{240}$ for interest, then pay $300$.

If you start to distribute you can see the pattern:

$d_m = ...\frac{241}{240}(\frac{241}{240}^2(24000) - \frac{241}{240}300-300)-300...$

$d_m = ...\frac{241}{240}(\frac{241}{240}^3(24000) - \frac{241}{240}^2300-\frac{241}{240}300)-300)...$

So I hope you can see that the final equation would look somthing like this:

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m24000 - 300\frac{241}{240}^{m-1} - 300\frac{241}{240}^{m-2}...$

which is the same as

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m24000 - 300(\frac{241}{240}^{m-1} +\frac{241}{240}^{m-2}...)$

switched around:

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m24000 - 300(\frac{241}{240}^{1} +\frac{241}{240}^{2}...\frac{241}{240}^{m-1})$

Ok, lets consider the series (lets call it S) in the middle:

$S = \frac{241}{240}^{1} +\frac{241}{240}^{2}...\frac{241}{240}^{m-1}$

if we multiply by $\frac{241}{240}$ we get

$S*\frac{241}{240} = \frac{241}{240}^{2} +\frac{241}{240}^{3}...\frac{241}{240}^{m}$

subtracting $S*\frac{241}{240}$ from $S$ we get:

$S-(S*\frac{241}{240}) = \frac{241}{240}^1 - \frac{241}{240}^m$

and the right side equals $S(1-\frac{241}{240})$ because of the distributive property.So

$S=\frac{\frac{241}{240} - \frac{241}{240}^m}{ 1-\frac{241}{240}}$

$S=\frac{\frac{241}{240} - \frac{241}{240}^m}{ \frac{-1}{240}}$

$S=-240(\frac{241}{240} - \frac{241}{240}^m)$

And finally...

$S=-240\frac{241}{240} + 240\frac{241}{240}^m$

Back to our original equation:

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m24000 - 300(\frac{241}{240}^{1} +\frac{241}{240}^{2}...\frac{241}{240}^{m-1})$

We now know that the middle series = $-240\frac{241}{240} + 240\frac{241}{240}^m$, so we can substitute:

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m24000 - 300(-240\frac{241}{240} + 240\frac{241}{240}^m)$

now we can plug in $5*12$ months for m, and see if his debt is payed off:

$d_{60} = 10698.78343$

obviously not, so now we have to pay $200$ a month, which means we have to change the "$-300$" to a "$-200$" and now that the debt is $10698.78343$, change $24000$ to $10698.78343$.

Our new equation looks like this:

$d_m=\frac{241}{240}^m10698.78343 - 200(-240\frac{241}{240} + 240\frac{241}{240}^m)$

Now we just have to set $d_m$ to zero and solve:

$0=\frac{241}{240}^m10698.78343 - 200(-240\frac{241}{240} + 240\frac{241}{240}^m)$

$0=\frac{241}{240}^m10698.78343 + \frac{241*-240*-200}{240} + -200*240\frac{241}{240}^m$

$0=\frac{241}{240}^m10698.78343 + 48200 -48000\frac{241}{240}^m$

$-48200=\frac{241}{240}^m(10698.78343 -48000)$

$\frac{-48200}{10698.78343 -48000}=\frac{241}{240}^m$

$m = log_{\frac{241}{240}}\frac{-48200}{10698.78343 -48000}$

we get $m=61.648$ this means that it took 61 months to complete the payments AFTER 5 years.

So the total dollars he spent was $(5*12)*300 + 61.648*200 = 30329.60334$

So the total interest he paid was $30329.60334 - 24000 = 6329.60332$ dollars in interest

It took him 5 years + $\frac{61.648}{12} = 10.137$ years.

Whew. If you are looking for more help, [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq_induction/geometric-sequence-series/v/geometric-series-sum-to-figure-out-mortgage-payments) is a great kahn academy video.

Comment: WOW!!!! That was a great help to me!  I'm new to this site, but is there a way to vote for you as best answer?

Comment: And I typed the problem wrong...it is supposed to be $24,500.  Would I just substitute that in where you have all the $24,000, or would it change other factors as well?

Comment: Also, can you explain where you got the 241/240?

Comment: Yes, you could just substitute $24500$ in for $24000$. However, you would have to reevaluate $d_{60}$, and that would change the answer when you solve for $d_0$ the second time. the $\frac{241}{240}$ is the interest. It is the fractional version of $1 + \frac{.05}{12}$ So when you multiply by $\frac{241}{240}$ you are adding the interest to the current amount. There should also be a check mark just to the left of my answer to accept it. Thanks for your enthusiasm. I have been waiting to share this answer for a while :)

Comment: Can you explain how you got to the 61.648?  I'm having trouble figuring it out with the dm=0 with my new example with $24,500.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Thanks for all your help!